# Java matrix of ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

How can I define in Java a Matrix of ArrayList< String>.

I am trying with:

```
Arraylist<String>[][] data =new ArrayList<String>[5][5];
```

But that throws this error:

> Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList

Any idea?

Comment: I realize this might be a duplicate, but here is a solution that might work better than the accepted answer on the duplicate post : Generic type array is not allowed. One way to get around it could be something like a 2d array of objects and then you should be able to put ArrayLists in the array. I have not tested it, but something like this should work.

Object [][] data = new Object[5][5];
data[0][0] = new ArrayList<String>(); // etc .

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed in Java, why dont you try and use nested ArrayList like this `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>.`